# how to absorb the margin of child while only changing property of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a parent div inside which is a child div with margin-left 710px. I somehow want my parent div to absorb that extra 710px margin and the parent should remain at center of page, but there is a condition - I cannot change any property of child element or I cannot add any property to it as it is dynamic.

```css
.child {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 80px 0px 0px 710px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: max-content;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I have came so far. I have also attached an image for better understanding.
The image is just a reference to what I am trying to achieve.[image: Absorbing the extra child margin.]

Comment: I made a snippet of your CSS code by adding the div as you described. As you can see the code does not reproduce your image. Please update your question by providing a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is the purpose of this strange 710px margin. I can't think of any reason for it.

Comment: I also don't have any idea why it exists.  Actually the developer who has worked on it previously made this. And as I don't have access to backend code so I am stuck with this. Also the code will no reproduce the image. The image is just for reference to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @xdayaan can you elaborate further? You image shows the parent to the right and not centered, but you mentioned that the parent should remain in the center of the page.